# Why is this for loop starting at index 1 instead of index 0?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, nested

I am trying to get a better understanding of a nested for loop in python:

```
nums = [2,4,6,8,10]

for i in range(len(nums)):
    for j in range(i):
        print("i: " + str(i))
        print("j: " + str(j))
```

i is starting at index 1 instead of index 0, but if I change the range of `for j in range(i)` to anything other than the variable i, it starts at index 0.

If someone could quickly explain the functionality of this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect, and what is it actually? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood As stated in the original question, i prints out starting at index 1 instead of index 0. I was just confused on why index 0 was being skipped for i, but it was explained below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `i=0`, `range(i)` is empty, so it skips the inner loop:

```
>>> list(range(0))
[]
```

Comment: Simple enough. Thank you!